# Custom JSONConverter in NewtonsoftJson for Serialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I wanted to write custom JSON converter in newtonsoftjson library for serialization :

Requirement snippet:

```json
{
   "Roles":[
      {
         "Role":[
            {
               "LEAssociateTypeId":"101",
               "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Client/Counterparty",
               "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-11-30T08:35:01",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
            },
            {
               "LEAssociateTypeId":"5501",
               "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Principal",
               "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-11-29T08:50:34",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

To :

```json
{
   "Roles":[
      {
         "Role":{
            "LEAssociateTypeId":"101",
            "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Client/Counterparty",
            "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-11-30T08:35:01",
            "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
            "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
         }
      },
      {
         "Role":{
            "LEAssociateTypeId":"5501",
            "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Principal",
            "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-11-29T08:50:34",
            "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
            "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Since Roles is a dynamic object cannot define corresponding class for it.

I have also checked online documentation Role is converted to an array as per as https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.html

Source Code written :

```
public class customconverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject o = (JObject)t;
            foreach(var a in _validcollectionList)
            {
                if (o[a] != null && o[a].Count() > 0)
                {
                    var test = o[a][0];
                    var test1 = test["Role"];
                    var test2 = o[a] as JArray;
                    if (test1 != null && test1.Count() > 1)
                    {
                        foreach (var a1 in test1)
                        {
                            JObject obj = new JObject {
                                { "Role", a1 }
                            };
                            test2.Add(obj);
                        }
                    }
                    test.Remove();
                }
            }
            o.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

[11/12/2021] Updates : To be precise complete json is like:

```
{
  "Message": {
    "MessageInfo": {
      "Guid": "a2152d96-c202-4c08-a4a7-2331a648b586",
      "SourceId": "101",
    },
   "Roles":[
      {
         "Role":[
            {
               "LEAssociateTypeId":"101",
               "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Client/Counterparty",
               "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-11-30T08:35:01",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
            },
            {
               "LEAssociateTypeId":"5501",
               "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Principal",
               "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-11-29T08:50:34",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
               "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
}
```

also number of entities or attributes are dynamic , so above can vary.

Checked for solution , below line of code does not have roles details  =

var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);

only the messageinfo is present so it is not parsing complete json.

Also can't we do through custom json converter as original purpose is to convert xml to json through below line of code :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
  string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

but somehow newtonsoftjson library is grouping nodes with same name at same level into an array, so that's why this query comes.

kindly suggest.

[12/12/2021]: Sample XML Snippet :

```
<Message>
  <MessageInfo>
    <Guid>be190914-4b18-4454-96ec-67887dd4d7a7</Guid>
    <SourceId>101</SourceId>
  </MessageInfo>
<LegalEntities>
 <LegalEntity>
 <Roles>
        <Role>
          <LEAssociateTypeId>101</LEAssociateTypeId>
          <LEAssociateTypeId_Value>Client/Counterparty</LEAssociateTypeId_Value>
          <LastUpdatedDate>2021-08-07T23:05:17</LastUpdatedDate>
          <LegalEntityRoleStatusId>3</LegalEntityRoleStatusId>
          <LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>Active</LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>
        </Role>
        <Role>
          <LEAssociateTypeId>6000</LEAssociateTypeId>
          <LEAssociateTypeId_Value>Account Owner</LEAssociateTypeId_Value>
          <LastUpdatedDate>2021-08-07T21:20:07</LastUpdatedDate>
          <LegalEntityRoleStatusId>3</LegalEntityRoleStatusId>
          <LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>Active</LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>
        </Role>
        <Role>
          <LEAssociateTypeId>5003</LEAssociateTypeId>
          <LEAssociateTypeId_Value>Investment Manager</LEAssociateTypeId_Value>
          <LastUpdatedDate>2021-08-16T06:12:59</LastUpdatedDate>
          <LegalEntityRoleStatusId>3</LegalEntityRoleStatusId>
          <LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>Active</LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>
        </Role>
      </Roles>
 </LegalEntity>
 </LegalEntities>
</Message>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've fixed your json samples to be valid ones, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry to say but your edit gives more confusion than clarity. Now you are talking about xml file, there is also a new json file... I can alter my proposed solution to suite for your needs one more time, but I need to know that is there any other requirement or detail that I need to be aware of.

Comment: Since you have dynamic fields under the Role you can't define a model for that. Custom type converters are for specific types to override the default serialization and deserialization logic. In your case you want to transform a json to another, so there is no serialization involved if my understanding is correct about your question.

Comment: initial json provided was snippet only not the complete json , also along with roles entity there can be other entities as well for which same logic needs to be applied for which I can probably loop through afterwards according to alternative solution

Comment: Yes Roles is an dynamic entity ,can't define corresponding class to override default serialization while converting from xml to json , closet solution can be be alternative solution provided here(after update) , could you please help

Comment: Can you please share with us some sample xml as well?

Comment: Added Sample XML Snippet , kindly help

Comment: Are the MessageInfo's fields dynamic as well? Do they vary from payload to payload?

Comment: MessageInfo is static , number of fields remain same but can change in future

Comment: I've posted a new answer please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave another post because the OP's question has changed a lot since its original version.

Just to make sure that our understanding are the same:

- You want to use `JsonConvert.SerializeXNode` to convert a xml to a json
- This method by default does not handle arrays gracefully

  - [Related documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJsonForceArray.htm)
  - [Related github issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1968)
- You also want to change the representation of `Role` node to have a wrapper object around them

Let's tackle problems one by one

#### XML node to Json array

In order to treat the `LegalEntities` and `Roles` as array you need to add a custom attribute to these xml nodes: `json:Array = "true"`.

This `json` namespace has to be defined inside the xml like this: `xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json"`

So, you need to modify your xml to this (either manually or through `System.Xml` / `System.Xml.Linq`):

```xml
<Message xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
   <MessageInfo>
      <Guid>be190914-4b18-4454-96ec-67887dd4d7a7</Guid>
      <SourceId>101</SourceId>
   </MessageInfo>
   <LegalEntities json:Array="true">
      <LegalEntity>
         <Roles json:Array="true">
            <Role>
               <LEAssociateTypeId>101</LEAssociateTypeId>
               <LEAssociateTypeId_Value>Client/Counterparty</LEAssociateTypeId_Value>
               <LastUpdatedDate>2021-08-07T23:05:17</LastUpdatedDate>
               <LegalEntityRoleStatusId>3</LegalEntityRoleStatusId>
               <LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>Active</LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>
            </Role>
            <Role>
               <LEAssociateTypeId>6000</LEAssociateTypeId>
               <LEAssociateTypeId_Value>Account Owner</LEAssociateTypeId_Value>
               <LastUpdatedDate>2021-08-07T21:20:07</LastUpdatedDate>
               <LegalEntityRoleStatusId>3</LegalEntityRoleStatusId>
               <LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>Active</LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>
            </Role>
            <Role>
               <LEAssociateTypeId>5003</LEAssociateTypeId>
               <LEAssociateTypeId_Value>Investment Manager</LEAssociateTypeId_Value>
               <LastUpdatedDate>2021-08-16T06:12:59</LastUpdatedDate>
               <LegalEntityRoleStatusId>3</LegalEntityRoleStatusId>
               <LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>Active</LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value>
            </Role>
         </Roles>
      </LegalEntity>
   </LegalEntities>
</Message>
```

Now if you pass this to the `SerializeXNode` then you will get the following json:

```json
{
   "Message":{
      "MessageInfo":{
         "Guid":"be190914-4b18-4454-96ec-67887dd4d7a7",
         "SourceId":"101"
      },
      "LegalEntities":[
         {
            "LegalEntity":{
               "Roles":[
                  {
                     "Role":[
                        {
                           "LEAssociateTypeId":"101",
                           "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Client/Counterparty",
                           "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-08-07T23:05:17",
                           "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
                           "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
                        },
                        {
                           "LEAssociateTypeId":"6000",
                           "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Account Owner",
                           "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-08-07T21:20:07",
                           "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
                           "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
                        },
                        {
                           "LEAssociateTypeId":"5003",
                           "LEAssociateTypeId_Value":"Investment Manager",
                           "LastUpdatedDate":"2021-08-16T06:12:59",
                           "LegalEntityRoleStatusId":"3",
                           "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value":"Active"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

#### Transform `Role` nodes

In order to be able to perform some transformation you need to retrieve the appropriate node via the `SelectToken` method

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc);

var root = JObject.Parse(json);
var roles = root.SelectToken("$.Message.LegalEntities[0].LegalEntity.Roles") as JArray;
if (roles == null) return;

var role = roles.First().SelectToken("$.Role") as JArray;
if (roles == null) return;
```

- The first `SelectToken` retrieved the `Roles` collection
- The second `SelectToken` retrieved the `Role` collection

Now, let's do the transformation:

```
var roleNodes = new List<JObject>();
foreach (var roleNode in role)
{
    roleNodes.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("Role", roleNode)));
}
```

Here we iterate through the `Role` collection and we are creating a wrapper object around it which has a single property called Role.

Finally we have to replace the `Roles` collection with the newly created `JObject`s. This can be achieved with the following simple command:

```
roles.ReplaceAll(roleNodes);
```

---

For the sake of completeness here is the full code:

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText("sample.xml");

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc);

var root = JObject.Parse(json);
var roles = root.SelectToken("$.Message.LegalEntities[0].LegalEntity.Roles") as JArray;
if (roles == null) return;

var role = roles.First().SelectToken("$.Role") as JArray;
if (roles == null) return;

var roleNodes = new List<JObject>();
foreach (var roleNode in role)
{
    roleNodes.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("Role", roleNode)));
}

roles.ReplaceAll(roleNodes);
Console.WriteLine(root);
```

and the emitted output:

```json
{
  "Message": {
    "MessageInfo": {
      "Guid": "be190914-4b18-4454-96ec-67887dd4d7a7",
      "SourceId": "101"
    },
    "LegalEntities": [
      {
        "LegalEntity": {
          "Roles": [
            {
              "Role": {
                "LEAssociateTypeId": "101",
                "LEAssociateTypeId_Value": "Client/Counterparty",
                "LastUpdatedDate": "2021-08-07T23:05:17",
                "LegalEntityRoleStatusId": "3",
                "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value": "Active"
              }
            },
            {
              "Role": {
                "LEAssociateTypeId": "6000",
                "LEAssociateTypeId_Value": "Account Owner",
                "LastUpdatedDate": "2021-08-07T21:20:07",
                "LegalEntityRoleStatusId": "3",
                "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value": "Active"
              }
            },
            {
              "Role": {
                "LEAssociateTypeId": "5003",
                "LEAssociateTypeId_Value": "Investment Manager",
                "LastUpdatedDate": "2021-08-16T06:12:59",
                "LegalEntityRoleStatusId": "3",
                "LegalEntityRoleStatusId_Value": "Active"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , let me check

Comment: Hi,  line of code : var root = JObject.Parse(jsonText); is not parsing whole json , I see MessageInfo entity only

Comment: @tusharbeniwal Does your jsonText variable contain all data? So before you try to semi parse it, is the input correct?

Comment: checked again , now working for solution provided , will update further

Comment: above solution provided working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct then you want to do the followings:

- `Roles` should have two children instead of one
- `Role` should not be a collection rather a property

I think the easiest way to do this transformation is via [Linq to Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = "...";
    var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
    Console.WriteLine(TranformJson(semiParsedJson));
}

static string TranformJson(JObject semiParsed)
{
    if (!semiParsed.TryGetValue("Roles", out var roles))
        return null;
    if (roles is not JArray rolesArray)
        return null;

    var firstRole = (JObject)rolesArray.First();

    if (!firstRole.TryGetValue("Role", out var role))
        return null;
    if (role is not JArray roleArray)
        return null;

    var newStructure = new
    {
        Roles = roleArray.Children()
            .Select(role => new { Role = role })
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newStructure);
}
```

1. We parse the json as a `JObject` to help us retrieve specific properties / collection
2. We try to retrieve the `Roles` property if it does not exist then we return `null`
3. If it exist then we check whether it is a collection. I've used here C# 9's new [`is not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) feature
4. If it is not a collection then we return with `null`
5. If it is a collection then we retrieve the first element from it
6. We do the same steps (2-4) to retrieve the `Role` collection
7. We create a new anonymous object to represent the data in the desired way
8. We do some transformation on the most inner objects as well
9. Finally we serialize the newly constructed object to string to have the desired output
10. Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , let me check

Comment: @tusharbeniwal Did it work for you?

Comment: I have updated in question , please assist.